# ESP32 Can't Serve a TTF File from SPIFFS

Tags: webserver, esp32

Why can't I serve a TTF file with my ESP32?

```
server.on("fonts/Helvetica_LT_67_Medium_Condensed.ttf", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request) { request->send(FILESYSTEM, "fonts/Helvetica_LT_67_Medium_Condensed.ttf", "application/x-font-ttf"); });
```

If I navigate to `http://192.168.1.1/fonts/Helvetica_LT_67_Medium_Condensed.ttf` I get a 404 because my `server.onNotFound` function triggers.

Yes, the folder and file are both flashed to the SPIFFS.

Thanks.

**EDIT**
Solved the issue. It was none of those causing the problem, but rather the filename was too long. For some reason, the ESP32 didn't like having a string called `Helvetica_LT_67_Medium_Condensed.ttf`, but `HLT67MC.ttf` was fine.

Comment: That depends on what the rest of your code is doing. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: relative paths make sense at browser side in context of current request but they make no sense for server-side - most likely you forgot to add preceding slash to URI , i.e. ```server.on("/fonts/.......```